# ASP.NET web service remove documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I want to remove default documentation and show my method on blank page, I try but I'm getting an error.
How can I show my method on a blank page?

I try following on **web.config**

```
<protocols>
          <remove name="Documentation">
          </remove>
 </protocols>
```

after adding i am getting error

Request format is unrecognized. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
Stack Trace: 



[InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +170817
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +209
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +47
   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) +226
   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +156
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Please check my attachments,i just want to show black box area

[image]

Comment: Remove documentation of WHAT?

Comment: And ASP.NET, which version / edition?

Comment: @chade_ please check attachments

Comment: @HenkHolterman,<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

Comment: There are an awful lot of asp.net  versions targeting CLR 4.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but in case of

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <remove name="Documentation"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

it is expected that request to `<webservice>.asmx` gives

```
InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized.
```

Usually the documentation is good to remove on production environment where you don't want to leak the details of your web service.

In case you want to customize the page, search for

```
<webServices>
  ...
  <wsdlHelpGenerator href="<custom page>"/>
  ...
</webServices>
```

[Improving the ASP.NET Webservice Help Generator to Reflect Inheritance](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28635/Improving-the-ASP-NET-Webservice-Help-Generator-to)